# How to find the normal to the boundary of $\{ (x,t) \in \mathbb R^n \times (a,b): |x|<r, 0<a<t<b \}$?

Tags: geometry, differential-topology, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

A subset $S$ of  $\mathbb R^n$ is called a hypersurface of class $C^k (1\leq k \leq \infty)$ if for
every $x_0\in S$ there is an open set $V\subset \mathbb R^n$ containing $x_0$ and a real-valued
function  $\phi \in C^k(V)$ such that  $\nabla  \phi$ is nonvanishing on $S\cap V$ and $S\cap V = \{ x\in V: \phi(x)=0 \}.$

With $S, V, \phi$ as above, the vector $v(x)$ is perpendicular to $S$ at $x$
for every $x\in S\cap V.$ We shall always suppose that $S$ is oriented, that
is, that we have made a choice of unit vector $v(x)$ for each $x\in S$, varying
continuously with $x$ which is perpendicular to $S$ at $x.$ 
$v(x)$ will be called
the normal to $S$ at $x.$

Note: On $S\cap V,$ we have $v(x)= \pm \frac{\nabla \phi (x)}{|\nabla \phi (x)|}.$

Fix $r, a, b\in (0, \infty)$ with $a<b.$

Let $A= \{ (x,t) \in \mathbb R^n \times (a,b):  |x|<r, 0<a<t<b \}.$

> Questions: (a) What is the boundary of $A$ in $\mathbb R^n \times (0, \infty)$? (The boundary of $A$ is denoted by $\partial A.$) (b) How to find the normal $v(z)$ to $\partial A$
>   at $z$ in $\partial A$? (Is $\partial A$
>   hypersurface of class $C^1$? What is $\phi $ for $\partial A$
>   ?)

Comment: @Paul: I know that just for $\{|x|=r\},$ the $v(x)=\frac{x}{r}$

Comment: @Paul: Is $\partial A$ correct?

Comment: Your boundary is incorrect, you're missing some parts of it. Also, guesses are alright to get started, but try to prove them. If it doesn't work, then maybe your guess is wrong.

Comment: Do you still need help with that problem, or did you solve it?